# Restore integrated terminal session with last Working Directory on Git Bash

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, git-bash

usually when we exit the terminal and re open it, it will restore our terminal and tabs, its good a feature, but can it restore our last cwd too? i think it supposed to, but i cant get it working on my terminal.

the session doesnt save my last working directory
[image]

it said `session contents restored`

the directory before that is `.../shop/shop-next`, but after restored its just `.../shop`

i want it to be the same as  before (`.../shop/shop-next`) after restored

the setting related is :

[image] on setting "persistent session revive process", it said that it supposed to restore the CWD depends on whether it supported by the terminal

i dont know if git bash is support this feature, so here is my question:

1. is there a way to get it done?(without using *extension*)
2. what terminal/profile/bash support this feature.

Answer (score 1):

*(Sorry, this might not work for you, as you use tabs, but probably would bring you some ideas to improve.)*

I used some trick, I was writing path of changed directory into a file, and used this saved path on session load.

So, if we are talking about Git Bash for Windows (or any similar to MINGW64) or *nix systems, I used this code in .bashrc file:

```bash
# == Use changed/default directory on load ==

# Remember changed directory
DEFAULT_DIR=~
cd() { builtin cd ${@} && keep_last_dir; }
keep_last_dir() { pwd > ~/.bashrc.last_dir; }

if [ -z "${BASHRC_INIT}" ]; then
  export BASHRC_INIT=1
  readonly BASHRC_INIT
  change_dir=${DEFAULT_DIR}
  if [[ ${HOME} != $(pwd) ]] && [[ -f ~/.bashrc.last_dir ]]; then
    change_dir=$(cat ~/.bashrc.last_dir)
  fi
  # go to default/prev directory
  [ -d ${change_dir} ] && cd ${change_dir}
fi
# == == == == == == == == == == == == == == ==
```

You may change this line: `DEFAULT_DIR=~`

On first open it always would return you to last directory location.